# Jump from Assembly (not inline) to C program label

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

As stated, I'm not using inline assembly. If that's the *only* way to do it then I suppose I will convert it.

My instructions to `je tree` in assembly.s for example aren't jumping back to the labels in the C program, and it seems they're not even getting out of the loop asking for the user's name.

I recognize that those labels seem to be the syntax that may only be usable inside Assembly, but let me know if there's a different/better way to jump from the assembly comparisons back to specific code blocks in the C program.

I'm still learning, so there are likely many errors or worst-practices scattered around.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "header.h"

//Plot : User must get the stick, line and bait in order to catch a huge fish to win a fishing contest and return home.

#define stick (1 << 0)
#define line (1 << 1)
#define bait (1 << 2)

int go = 0;

int main () {
    
    
    int fishing_pole = 0;   //A fully assembled fishing pole is int == 7
    char name[20];
    int len;
    int tries = 1;
    int fish_size = 20;
    time_t start, end;
    int elapsed;

    //Intro
    printf("You wake up on a sandbar in a place you don't recognize");
    elipses();
    sleep(2);
    printf("\nSomeone calls out to you in the distance, and as you turn to look you see someone approaching you.\n");
    
    //Get the name
    yellow();
    printf("You must be the last entry for the fishing contest!\nWhat's your name?\n");

    //MY NAME IS...
    //Keeps user looped until they enter a name under 20 characters.
    while (1) {

        blue();
        printf("My name is... ");
        scanf(" %s", name);
        reset();
        len = strlen(name);
        
        if ( len < 20 ) {

            yellow();
            printf("Alright, %s, All you'll need is a fishing pole!\n", name);
            elipses();
            printf("You don't have a fishing pole?\n");
            sleep(1);
            printf("Well that's alright, certainly you could make one with some materials nearby!\nLet me know when you've got a pole and we can begin!\n");
            reset();
            nav_prompt(go);

        } else {

        printf("I don't really know if I can remember that long of a name, maybe give me a shorter nickname I can call you?\n");

        }
    }
    

        tree:
            if ( !(fishing_pole & 0001) ) { 
                printf("You approach the tree you saw and pull a branch from it. This looks like a good fishing pole!\n");
                fishing_pole |= stick;
                nav_prompt(go);
            } else {
                printf("You've already got the stick!\n ");
                nav_prompt(go);
            }
        dirt:
            if ( !(fishing_pole & 0010) ) {
                printf("You approach the pile of dirt, dig for a moment and pull a worm from the ground.\nThis should be good for bait!\n");
                nav_prompt(go);
            } else {
                printf("You've already got your hands dirty and dug up the bait!\n");
                nav_prompt(go);
            }
        spider:
            if ( !(fishing_pole & 0100) ) {
                printf("You approach the spider web, pull it down and spin it into a strong line!\nThis ought to work for a fishing line.");
                nav_prompt(go);
            } else {
                printf("You've already got the spider web for line, now get outta here before the spider finds out!\n");
                nav_prompt(go);
            } 
        crowd:
            if ( !(fishing_pole & 0111) ) {
                yellow();
                printf("You think you're ready, %s? Let's see if you've got a fishing pole!\n", name);
                if ( fishing_pole == 7 ) {
                    printf("Hey that looks great, let's get to fishing!");
                    fishing();
                } else {
                    printf("Hey it looks like you're missing something, %s. Finish your pole and we'll wait!\n", name);
                }
            }
        bad:
            printf("Not sure where you think you're going, %s, but it's in the wrong direction!\n", name);
            nav_prompt(go);

        fish:
            reset();
            //Actual gameplay!!
            printf("You line up next to the other fishing competitors and cast your line.\n");
            while (1) {
                //regenerate how long it takes for a fish to hook every loop
                int random = (rand() % 3) + 1;

                while ( random < 0 ) {
                elipses();
                --random;
                }
                //calculate how long it takes for the player to reel
                printf("Fish on! Press any key to reel it in!\n");
                start = time(NULL);
                getchar();
                end = time(NULL);
                elapsed = difftime(end, start);

                //Fish get easier to catch on every attempt
                if ( elapsed > tries ) {
                    printf("The fish got away!\n");
                    printf("You cast your line again.\n");
                    ++tries;
                    --fishing_pole;
                } else {
                    printf("You reel in the fish!");
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            if ( (fishing_pole - tries) < 1 ) {
                fishing_pole = 1;
                yellow();
                printf("The fish you caught was %d inches long. Unfortunately that's not big enough and you were beaten...\nGo ahead and try to make a better fishing pole, and try and catch the first couple fish next time!\n", fishing_pole);
                fishing_pole = 0;
                nav_prompt(go);
            } else {
                yellow();
                printf("The fish you caught was %d inches long!\n", fishing_pole);
                printf("Really great work, it looks like you can leave this place finally, %s!\n", name);
                printf("Have a safe trip and come back to visit us sometime!\n");
                reset();
                elipses();
                printf("Your vision begins to go blurry and you feel dizzy");
                elipses();
            }

            
            
            
    return 0;
}
```

assembly.s:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix 

extern go

global tree
global dirt
global spider
global crowd
global navigation
global fishing

    navigation: 
        mov rax, 1
        cmp rax, go
        je tree
        mov rax, 2
        cmp rax, go
        je dirt
        mov rax, 3
        cmp rax, go
        je spider
        mov rax, 4
        cmp rax, go
        je crowd
        jmp bad
        xor rdx, rdx
        ret

    fishing:
        jmp fish
        ret
```

functions.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void red () {
  printf("\033[0;31m");
}

void green () {
    printf("\033[0;32m");
}

void yellow () {
  printf("\033[0;33m");
}

void blue () {
    printf("\033[0;34m");
}

void reset () {
  printf("\033[0m");
}

void elipses () {
    printf(".");
    sleep(1);
    printf(".");
    sleep(1);
    printf(".\n");
    sleep(1);
}

int navigation(int x){};

int nav_prompt (int x) {
  reset();
  printf("You look around and see a tree, a pile of dirt, a spider's web and a few people standing around down the beach.\nWhere would you like to go? [1/2/3/4, Tree/Dirt/Spider Web/Group of people]\n");
    //[1/2/3/4, Tree/Dirt/Spider Web/Group of people]
    scanf(" %d", &x);
    navigation(x);
}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

void red ();

void blue ();

void green ();

void yellow ();

void reset ();

void elipses ();

int navigation(int x);

int nav_prompt ();

void fishing();

#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the exact tool chain you are using, your assembly may not be able to see the labels in the `c` code. --- There's a much cleaner way to do this, though: have your `navigation` function return a value corresponding to the labels and then use a `switch` on the `c` side to select what code to execute based on the returned value.

Comment: Also note that C passes arguments by value so your `scanf(" %d", &x);` will read into `x` not into `go`. While you do pass `x` into the `navigation` function that does not use it and instead references `go` which is not set. Furthermore `cmp` can take an immediate so you don't have to go through `rax`. In any case, you can't just jump out of a function and into the middle of another and expect things to work, even if the symbols were accessible.

Comment: `global tree` exports that symbol *from* the asm file.  You want `extern tree` to access a symbol from another object file. But that won't work either because the C compile won't use `.globl` on the goto label inside a function: it's totally unsupported to jump into the middle of a function so C compilers will just use auto-numbered labels like `.L123:`.  GNU C labels-as-values (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) will let you take the address of a C goto-label, which you could maybe abuse to jump into the function from outside, but expect the stack layout to be wrong etc

Comment: GNU C inline asm *does* support `asm goto("... stuff that might jump to one of the specified labels" : ... : "r" (input1) : "memory", "eax" : "tree", "dirt", ...)`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels

Comment: Is this just an exercise in learning assembly?  Or is there some real problem you're trying to solve?  If it's performance, this is very unlikely to be better than what `gcc -O3` will do on its own with pure C logic such as a `switch() { case 1: goto tree; ...}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be that you never change the value of go.
A secondary problem... I have a feeling when you call navigation, it is goign to the function defined in your c file, and not the label you made in your ASM.
I could be wrong though.

After playing with this and completely ommitting your ASM file...
[Here is where I did that...](https://onlinegdb.com/LZHFSzQeh)
It seems like it is completely not using your ASM file.

If the goal is to learn, I recommend learning using QtSpim.
There are lots of resources for MIPS, and it is a really good way to begin. Of course it works differently than x86, but the basics are the same. Its the details that change.